# How Do I draw Vertices using an Index Buffer using OpenGL ES 2.0 and Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0, indices, vertices

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in OpenGL ES 2.0. I've searched and searched and could not find an answer to how to do this. I've used a book and done it in DirectX Before which was pretty straight forward, so I do understand how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this Blog:

- http://opengles2learning.blogspot.de/

It has lots of stuff which will probably be interesting for you.
And for every post sourcecode is provided.

For basic OpenGL ES 2.0 Setup on Android see:

- http://opengles2learning.blogspot.de/2011/05/first-experience-with-opengl-es2-on_15.html

An example for using an Index Buffer can be found here:

- http://opengles2learning.blogspot.de/2011/06/texturing-cube-applying-same-texture-on_04.html